# Can't deploy a bna to an existing Hyperledger Fabric installation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deploy my BNA (developed on my dev machine) to an existing Hyperledger Fabric installation. The Fabric was installed by another dev whom I'm unable to contact. I am able to fire up the Playground and see another deployed network, but I'm unable to deploy my own:

`$ composer network install -a ./dist/noiz.bna -c PeerAdmin@composer-network-a
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed`

I tried creating a new PeerAdmin card using the Playground, but deploying with this card won't help. The result was different (maybe because I used admin/adminpw for creating the card):

`✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Authorization for INSTALL has been denied (error-Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]))
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed`

I'm using composer 0.19.5. I believe TLS is on.

Here's my `docker ps`, just in case:

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
aa4d7a9d2ccd        dev-peer0.a.example.com-export_import-0.0.1-5d8a845d4c4a29001b15ec77fa81c2b896564f083c5b2d55a9a5e5252cf98754   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                           dev-peer0.a.example.com-export_import-0.0.1
5f7a9b240371        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                           "peer node start"        29 hours ago        Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.a.example.com
32f274f31bd6        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6                                                                        "tini -- /docker-ent…"   29 hours ago        Up 4 hours          4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb.peer0.a.example.com
54b8b4e2816d        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                             "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   29 hours ago        Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.a.example.com
ddb2594ddcfd        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                        "orderer"                29 hours ago        Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com`

Here's the output of `channel list`:

`$ docker exec peer0.a.example.com peer channel list
2018-05-22 18:37:26.073 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-05-22 18:37:26.073 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-05-22 18:37:26.076 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-05-22 18:37:26.076 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: plaintext: 0A90070A5B08031A0B08E6C691D80510...631A0D0A0B4765744368616E6E656C73
2018-05-22 18:37:26.077 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: 138FECCD301FA969418E2DE047CEA7B1E506880E726EC0F14E2542D33C7A0CCE
2018-05-22 18:37:26.080 UTC [main] main -> INFO 006 Exiting.....
Channels peers has joined:
mychannel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little difficult as your colleague has set up a Custom Fabric.

This error `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed` usually comes back quickly and means that the CLI can't find the Fabric specified in the connection.json file for the Card used.  So you could look at the connection.json for the card and see what Fabric and what URLs are specified.  The file will be something like `~/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@composer-network-a/connection.json`  the file will be difficult to read with no whitespace or newlines so pasting it into a JSON viewer would help.

Have you tried `composer card list` to see if there are any other admin cards available?

You say you can fire up Playground - is than in a Docker Container or on the CLI?

If you have access to the folders where your colleague generated the Crypto material you may be able to create a new Admin card - the composer [single org](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org) and [multi-org](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) tutorials show how to build cards based on existing crypto material.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! We ended up setting up a different instance that worked and terminating the one that didn't, so now I can't check anything, but hope it'll be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

is your fabric running?

if not, start it after redirecting in the directory where your startFabric.sh file lies, and then direct yourself back in the folder where your .bna file is.

Comment: As I said in the OP, "I am able to fire up the Playground and see another deployed network"